# c# look in text file for a certain string if exists do something

Tags: c#

ok what im trying to do is load a text file search it for a certain string if the string exists then it will will disable button

if it don't exist it will Wright to the file

```
if (File.Exists(hostfile))
{
    {
        string s = "elfenliedtopfan5 programupdate";

        string file = hostfile;
        List<string> lines = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file));
        int index = lines.FindLastIndex(item => item.Contains("elfenliedtopfan5 programupdate"));
        if (index != -1)
        {
            lines.Insert(index + 1, s);//""
        }
        //  System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
        MessageBox.Show("text test 1 found");
    }
}
else
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("text not found would you like to add it ", "Text Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(hostfile))
        {               
            sw.WriteLine("elfenliedtopfan5 update");
            sw.Close();
            messagebox.show("done");
        }
    }
}
```

but even know it does exist it will add it again and im confused to why this is the case any help would be appropriated

**elfenliedtopfan5**

Comment: What button are you suppose to disable?  What do you mean by "it will add it again"?  Add what?

Comment: I don't know if I understand the problem, but in your `IF` block you add your string to the `lines` collection, but you never write it to the file. Furthmore, you display a message box saying the text was found regardless of whether or not it was *actually* found. You should include that in your nested `IF` statement where you check `index`. Finally, as @juharr pointed out, no where do you disable a button in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way to read from or write to a text file:

```
string filename=@"D:\file.txt";
string value="your value"
var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
if (content.Contains(value))
    this.Button1.Enabled = false;
else
    System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(filename, new string(){value} );
```

Comment: If you're splitting on spaces, would `Contains` work when the value he's trying to find contains a space?

Comment: thank you all :) sab669 was right if i added contains it works perfectly thank you all for your quick replies :)